# Why are dead links redirecting to the home page on my Astro site deployed on AWS Amplify?

Tags: aws-amplify, astrojs

I have a static Astro website deployed to AWS Amplify for hosting. I initially missed a dead link because it was linking to the home page instead of the dedicated `404.astro` page.

How can I get my 404 page to show for dead/invalid URL instead of the home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, AWS Amplify sets up a redirect rule in your app that redirects to the root `/index.html` page. This is done because single page applications (SPA) often have a single root `index.html` file that hosts the frontend framework. The redirect is necessary to allow deep linking into the SPA which does its own internal routing.

Since Astro is a static site generator (SSG) it creates a directory structure and puts a separate `index.html` inside each each directory. It also has a dedicated `404.html` that it generates.

This means we need to adjust the redirect rule:

- Open the AWS Console
- Open the AWS Amplify service
- Open your Amplify app
- Click `Rewrites and redirects` in the "App Settings" sidebar

Change the rewrite rule from this

```
Source Address   Target address   Type
/<*>             /index.thml      404 (rewrite)
```

To this

```
Source Address   Target address   Type
/<*>             /404.thml        404 (rewrite)
```